# Conver date time string to D3 date time

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to covert a string in a csv file that has a date time in the following format: "03/16/2016 09:30" to d3 date time.

```
    var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%m/%d/%Y %h:%m");
    var t = formatTime("03/10/2016 09:30");
    console.log(t);
```

I'm trying to follow the following documentation:
https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format
But, the following is what is printed to the console:

```
NaN/NaN/0NaN h:NaN
```

I am using d3 version 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues,

First, if taking a string and converting it to a date you need to use `d3.timeParse`, you are using `d3.timeFormat` which is used to take a date and produce a string.

Second, you have an error in your format specifier: `"%m/%d/%Y %h:%m"`
There are two months, `%m`, in the specifier, but you probably want the second `%m` to be minutes, which is `%M`. Also, hours are not `%h` but either `%I` or `%H`, the first being the specifier for hours on a 12 hour clock and the second being hours on a 24 hour clock.

Using d3.timeParse and `"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M"` as the specifier we can parse the string and get a date object:

```js
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M");
var t = parseTime("03/10/2016 09:30");
console.log(t);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Getting d3 time after using your solution.